# Why must UIKit operations be performed on the main thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uikit, posix

I am trying to understand why UI operations can't be performed using multiple threads. Is this also a requirement in other frameworks like OpenGL or cocos2d?

How about other languages like C# and javascript? I tried looking in google but people mention something about POSIX threads which I don't understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Cocoa Touch, the `UIApplication` i.e. the instance of your application is attached to the main thread because this thread is created by `UIApplicatioMain()`, the entry point function of Cocoa Touch. It sets up main event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing events. Application's main event loop receives all the UI events i.e. touch, gestures etc.

From docs [`UIApplicationMain()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIApplicationMain),

> This function instantiates the application object from the principal class and instantiates the delegate (if any) from the given class and sets the delegate for the application. It also sets up the main event loop, including the application’s run loop, and begins processing events. If the application’s Info.plist file specifies a main nib file to be loaded, by including the NSMainNibFile key and a valid nib file name for the value, this function loads that nib file.

These application UI events are further forwarded to `UIResponder`'s following the chain of responders usually like `UIApplication`->`UIWindow`->`UIViewController`->`UIView`->subviews(`UIButton`,etc.)

Responders handle events like button press, tap, pinch zoom, swipe etc. which get translated as change in the UI. Hence as you can see these chain of events occur on main thread which is why `UIKit`, the framework which contains the responders should operate on main thread.

From docs again [`UIKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/Introduction/Introduction.html),

> For the most part, UIKit classes should be used only from an application’s main thread. This is particularly true for classes derived from UIResponder or that involve manipulating your application’s user interface in any way.

**EDIT**

**Why drawRect needs to be on main thread?**

`drawRect:` is called by `UIKit` as part of `UIView`'s lifecycle. So `drawRect:` is bound to main thread. Drawing in this way is expensive because it is done using the CPU on the main thread. The hardware accelerate graphics is provided by using the CALayer technique (Core Animation).

`CALayer` on the other hand acts as a backing store for the view. The view will then just display cached bitmap of its current state. Any change to the view properties will result in changes in the backing store which get performed by GPU on the backed copy. However, the view still needs to provide the initial content and periodically update view. I have not really worked on OpenGL but I think it also uses layers(I could be wrong).

I have tried to answer this to the best of my knowledge. Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree to most of what you have said. Let us assume that responder is on main thread and we need main thread to receive events but what about rendering UIView ? Why do we need drawRect on main thread. A lot of drawing could also be performed and optimized by muti-threading why does UIKit framework does not allow that? Also , I think UIKIt is GPU accelerated which uses multithreading. I might be wrong on this one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139300/having-uiview-drawrect-occur-in-a-background-thread

Comment: @KunalBalani: Just because you can't call UI methods from background threads doesn't mean the UI cannot utilise background threads. That's an implementation detail that is of no concern to you.

Answer (score 4):

from : https://www.objc.io/issues/2-concurrency/thread-safe-class-design/

> It’s a conscious design decision from Apple’s side to not have UIKit be thread-safe. Making it thread-safe wouldn’t buy you much in terms of performance; it would in fact make many things slower. And the fact that UIKit is tied to the main thread makes it very easy to write concurrent programs and use UIKit. All you have to do is make sure that calls into UIKit are always made on the main thread.

So according to this the fact that UIKit objects must be accessed on the main thread is a design decision by apple to favor performance.

Comment: I don't agree with this. This is all platforms including symbian , android ,blackberry and most them exists prior to iOS. Java servlets and other GUI tools have this too. They are not restricted to mobile based platform.

Answer (score 1):

C# behaves the same (see eg here: [Keep the UI thread responsive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994635.aspx)). UI updates have to be done in the UI thread - most other things should be done in the background hen possible.

If that wouldn't be the case there would probably be a synchronization hell between all updates that have to be done in the UI ...

Answer (score 0):

Every system, every library, needs to be concerned about thread safety and must do things to ensure thread safety, while at the same time looking after correctness and performance as well.

In the case of the iOS and MacOS X user interface, the decision was made to make the UI thread safe by only allowing UI methods to be called and executed on the main thread. And that's it.

Since there are lots of complicated things going on that would need at least serialisation to prevent total chaos from happening, I don't see very much gained from allowing UI on a background thread.

Answer (score -1):

Because you want the user to be able to see the UI changes as they happen. If you were to be able to perform UI changes in a background thread and display them when complete, it would seem the app doesn't behave right.

All non-UI operations (or at least the ones that are very costly, like downloading stuff or making database queries) should take place on a background thread, whereas all UI changes *must* always happen on the main thread to provide as smooth of a user experience possible.

I don't know what it's like in C# for Windows Phone apps, but I would expect it to be the same. On Android the system won't even let you do things like downloading on the main thread, making you create a background thread directly.

As a rule of thumb - when you think main thread, think "what the user sees".